# C++ Visual Studio 6 MFC Application

Tags: mfc

I have an old application, is there a quick way to get a face lift for the application without changing much code?
Some MFC emulator?

Comment: if it is a GUI application and looks boxy and 3-d, try adding a manifest file to use themed controls. The app will look modern straight away

Comment: You mean to say, you want to upgrade to the new version .  Is it?

Answer (score 1):

```
1)Create a file <yourapplication><.exe>.manifest

2)Paste the file in the same path as your exe 

3)Paste the following content inside the manifest file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
    version=""
    processorArchitecture=""
    name=""
    type=""
/>
<description></description>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.MSXML2"
            version=""
            processorArchitecture="X86"
            publicKeyToken=""
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
</assembly>

4) Launch the exe..
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to realize what you pretend to do from reading your vague question.

If you want to use more modern Visual Studio versions just open it on that version and a solution conversion wizard will be launched.

If you want some eye candy, just look to the Feature Pack. It has nice controls like Dockable Panes, Ribbon bars, etc. that will give a more modern look to your application.

If you want to change forms background, just read the WM_CTL_COLOR and OnCtlColor documentation and override the default behaviour.

And this list could go on through the infinite ...